# Law of large numbers

Tags: probability

Suppose that the randomized variables ${X_1, X_2, ...}$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with the expected value ${E(X_i)= 10}$ and standard deviation ${D(X_i) =1.5}$

a) approximate ${Pr(|\bar{X}_{20} -10| > 0.5)}$

b) how many variables means does it take to ensure that its probability does not surpass ${0.1}$?

What I've done so far

Regarding the Law of large numbers, I know that ${\bar{X_n}=\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}$. The answer for a) is 0.45, but I don't get that at all. Any thoughts? thanks on beforehand

Comment: It takes only *one* variable to ensure that *any* probability of *whatever* happening does not surpass 1.5, since probabilities are numbers within $[0,1]$ by definition... And (a) should probably read $\ldots > 0.5 \ldots$, not $\ldots > 05 \ldots$

Comment: yep thnx any other thoughts on a

Comment: Central limit theorem? It will yield an approximate distribution for $\overline{X}_{20}$, which you can then use to estimate the probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer $0.45$ is an **upper bound** from the [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality). Let $Y_{20}\equiv\bar{X}_{20}$. Then, $E(Y_{20})=10$ and $\text{Var}(Y_{20})=\frac{1.5^2}{20}$ so the Chebyshev's inequality gives
$$
\Pr(|\bar{X}_{20}-10)|>0.5)=\Pr(|Y_{20}-E(Y_{20})|>0.5)\leq\frac{\text{Var}(Y_{20})}{0.5^2}=0.45.
$$
For (b), you need to find $N$ such that
$$
\frac{1.5^2}{N\times 0.5^2}\leq 0.1\iff N\geq 90.
$$

---

If you want to **approximate** $\Pr(|\bar{X}_{20}-10)|>0.5)$, then a central limit theorem is likely a better tool. In this case, the summands are i.i.d. with finite variance so the Lindeberg-Lévy CLT applies: $Z_{20}\equiv\sqrt{20}(\bar{X}_{20}-10)$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1.5^2$. Thus,
$$
\Pr(|\bar{X}_{20}-10)|>0.5)=\Pr(|Z_{20}|>\sqrt{20}0.5)\approx 2\Phi\left(-\frac{\sqrt{20}0.5}{1.5}\right)\approx 0.136037.
$$

Comment: the question is under the Law of large numbers chapter so I'm guessing its the Llg that should be used. and yeah the answer is 0.45

regarding b)You're right, it seems as if I've been in a bit of a hurry whilst typing the question, sorry!

Besides I've translated the questions into english. Maybe a better translation would be: ''How many variables does one need to make a mean in order to ensure that its probabililty does not surpass 0.1''. The answer is ${n ≥ 90}$

Comment: holy molly!. the ruskijs knew what they were doing, seemingly as do you, yurnero!! cheers :)

Comment: Cheers to you too. The word "approximate" for (a) was seriously misleading. :)